# Frequent occurence of NonTransientFlatItemException Spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

Below is my spring batch configuration: I am using mutiresourcepartitioner for partitioning 10 files.

```
 <job id="test" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="master">
          <partition step="step2" partitioner="multiPartioner">
            <handler grid-size="3" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
          </partition>
        </step>
      </job>

      <bean id="multiPartioner"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner"
        scope="step">
        <property name="resources" value="file:#{jobParameters[fileDirectory]}/*" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="taskExecutor"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="30" />
      </bean>

        <step id="step2" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
          <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <chunk reader="multiReader" writer="testWriter"
              commit-interval="5000">
            </chunk>
          </tasklet>
        </step>

        <bean id="testWriter" class="org.test.customWriter" scope="step" />

        <bean id="multiReader"
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader"
            scope="step">
            <property name="resources" value="#{stepExecutionContext['fileResource']}" />
            <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemReader" />
      </bean>
```

But i am frequently gettting NonTransientFlatFileException : unable to read resource . On seeing the logs came to know that One thread is probably trying to read its next item from file 1 while another thread is closing the current completed input file 1 leading to I/o Exception.

We also tried to retry if this exception occurs but since it a nontransient exception we cant able to retry .

Is there any solution to overcome this exception in spring batch. Also this exception would have been faced by many people who are using partioning with multiresourceItemPartioner ?

Does grid size makes any impact in partioning ? Are any other configuration causing this problem to happen again ansd again?

Comment: have you tried reading directly using  the flatFileItemReader instead of MultiResourceItemReader?

Comment: Hi Luca Basso Ricci , No I haven't tried using FlatFileItemReader. I will try . But what will happen if I do so . If I do ,then can I overcome this exception ?

Comment: i have never used partitioner,but example i have found around never use a multiresource but the flatreader directly

Comment: K Luca Basso Ricci will try this option and let you know. Thnx for your reply. Any thing about grid size Impact on partioning?

Comment: from javadoc: Implementation of Partitioner that locates multiple resources and associates their file names with execution context keys. Creates an ExecutionContext per resource, and labels them as {partition0, partition1, ..., partitionN}. **The grid size is ignored.**

Comment: Hi Luca Basso Ricci , how can i append a current executing thread name to my writer? Please can u help me out of this

Comment: spEL doesn't help? Thread.getCurrentName() or similar?

Comment: Yeah i can able to get it in program via Thread.CurrentName() but cant able to assign the name in spring config. Thatz my problem

Comment: use spring expression language (spEL). with this scripting language you can use standard java method (like #{T(java.lang.Thread).getCurrentName()}